# How to Make flutter webview load only once?

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

when I switch from one page to another the state of my WebView isn't remembered and it reloads every time. how can prevent that?

I was expecting the web view to load only for the first time and remember it's state but it gets reloaded every time i navigate to that screen. how to make it remember the state?

Comment: Do you mean when you switch between app pages not pages inside WebView?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am clicking on back button and then when navigating again to the web view screen it gets reloaded again. I want to prevent that and make it remember it’s state.

Comment: Curious to see an answer... I have something somewhat similar... and I use a "Stack" for my webView that I can hide or make visible as needed... this could work for you, if you don't find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `PageView` with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`.

See this example app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final PageController _controller = PageController();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _controller.jumpToPage(index);
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          // selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'home'),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.web), label: 'web'),
          ]),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: const [MyDummyPage(), MyWebView()],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDummyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDummyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyDummyPage> createState() => _MyDummyPageState();
}

class _MyDummyPageState extends State<MyDummyPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late int count;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    count = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text('$count'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          count++;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}

class MyWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWebView> createState() => _MyWebViewState();
}

class _MyWebViewState extends State<MyWebView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return const WebView(initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev');
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. This solutions works for me as of now.